# How add Third UIView in UISplitViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

Can and how I add UIView above masterView in UISplitViewController. 
see example:
[image]

Comment: add a view in a master view. Or, if you want to add it above, just add 2 views on a master view: 1 being the top view and the other being a copy of a master view

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more advanced than what Novarg has suggested, use [`MGSplitViewController`](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController). You can then have a split view controller as the detail view of the top split view controller. MGSplitViewController also allows for resizable ratio so you can fit it as you like.